# Parts of my animation do not transition smoothly. Does anyone know where I should look to solve this?

Tags: animation, unreal-engine4

Here is my walking animation and the problem displayed. My setup consists of 1 blend space where the character walks forward, 90 degrees to the right, and 90 to the left; linked to an animation bp with a state machine with transitions from an idle state to this blend space and back. The transitions check to make sure that the character is not in the air and also that the input speeds match. As of yet I don't believe the issue resides with the animation bp, but in the blend space.

As you can see in the gif, when the character moves directly to the right, it smoothly transitions back to the idle state. However, when the character moves in any other direction, its transition back to the idle state appears as if the character is first pivoting to the right.

https://i.imgur.com/WgkUhAp.gifv

Answer (score 3):

Fixed it! changed target interpolation weight from 0 to 2 in the blend space settings.